# Youtube api how get replies to comments and likes

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, comments

To get comments using this

Comment Threads: list

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

But how get each comment replies, and check user like it or not, any knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [API Documentation of YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list), just must extend the `part` parameter with `replies`, like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&videoId=[VIDEO_ID]&key=[YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY]
```

The URL doesn't make much sense without a video ID and API key, so I added these too to the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`comments.list` method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) in retrieving comment replies. Here's an [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list):

```
// Call the YouTube Data API's comments.list method to retrieve
// existing comment
// replies.
               CommentListResponse commentsListResponse = youtube.comments().list("snippet")
                        .setParentId(parentId).setTextFormat("plainText").execute();
                List<Comment> comments = commentsListResponse.getItems();

                if (comments.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Can't get comment replies.");
                } else {
                    // Print information from the API response.
                    System.out
                            .println("\n================== Returned Comment Replies ==================\n");
                    for (Comment commentReply : comments) {
                        snippet = commentReply.getSnippet();
                        System.out.println("  - Author: " + snippet.getAuthorDisplayName());
                        System.out.println("  - Comment: " + snippet.getTextDisplay());
                        System.out
                                .println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                    }
                    Comment firstCommentReply = comments.get(0);
                    firstCommentReply.getSnippet().setTextOriginal("updated");
                    Comment commentUpdateResponse = youtube.comments()
                            .update("snippet", firstCommentReply).execute();
                    // Print information from the API response.
                    System.out
                            .println("\n================== Updated Video Comment ==================\n");
                    snippet = commentUpdateResponse.getSnippet();
                    System.out.println("  - Author: " + snippet.getAuthorDisplayName());
                    System.out.println("  - Comment: " + snippet.getTextDisplay());
                    System.out
                            .println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
```

Regarding likes, you may want to check out the [`snippet.viewerRating`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#snippet.viewerRating).

> The rating the viewer has given to this comment. Note that this property does not currently identify `dislike` ratings, though this behavior is subject to change. In the meantime, the property value is `like` if the viewer has rated the comment positively. The value is none in all other cases, including the user having given the comment a negative rating or not having rated the comment.
>
> Valid values for this property are:
>
> - like
> - none

Then check the [`snippet.likeCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#snippet.likeCount) to get the total number of likes (positive ratings) the comment has received.

Here's the [sample JSON structure](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#resource-representation) that shows the format of a `comments` resource.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#comment",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    ......
    "authorChannelId": {
      "value": string
    },
    ......
    "viewerRating": string,
    "likeCount": unsigned integer,
    ......
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!