# Gathering Youtube Top Comments Using YouTube API V3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to work with YouTube API V3 to extract the top 10 comments from a specific video. I'm currently using the below line to access the comments for a video. I have successfully grabbed comments from the video in question, but I have been unable to extract the TOP comments like the ones shown under the video on youtube.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=**YOUTUBEAPIKEY**&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet&videoId=**YOUTUBEVIDEOID**&maxResults=50
```

I've looked through the documentation at:

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list
```

But I haven't been able find anything that mentions this. Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by using the [`snippet.viewerRating`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#snippet.viewerRating), if you base the rank of the comment per number of likes as discussed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527147/youtube-api-how-get-replies-to-comments-and-likes). Then you can filter from the most number of like to the least. Placing the top comments at the top.

> The rating the viewer has given to this comment. Note that this
>   property does not currently identify **`dislike`** ratings, though
>   this behavior is subject to change. In the meantime, the property
>   value is **`like`** if the viewer has rated the comment positively.
>   The value is **`none`** in all other cases, including the user having
>   given the comment a negative rating or not having rated the comment.
>
> Valid values for this property are:
>
> - **`like`**
> - **`none`**

Here is the sample JSON structure for the **`comments`** resource format.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#comment",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    ......
    "authorChannelId": {
      "value": string
    },
    ......
    "viewerRating": string,
    "likeCount": unsigned integer,
    ......
  }
}
```